# unable to connect to wifi and don't have ethernet cable

Tags: 14.04, networking, drivers, broadcom

I have an old **HP Mini 110-1026NR** netbook. I recently installed **Ubuntu 14.04 LTS 32bit**. I am unable to connect to wifi and I do not have an ethernet cable, but I do have a working mac and a flash drive. The netbook has a Broadcom chipset **BCM4312** and its PCI-ID is [**14e4:4315**]. The current kernel in use is **b43-pci-bridge**. Please help.

Comment: I tried installing using Ubuntu support to update the drivers separately. I initially found a broadcom-sta-common_6.30.223.141-1_all.deb. I transferred and installed it. No change after reboot. I then went to the broadcom site and downloaded what looked like the correct driver as a .tar.gz file. I am unable to install it. ifconfig only lists eth0 and lo, still no wlan.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to find and download to a USB stick the following compressed, tar file:
broadcom-wl-5.100.138.tar.bz2

Copy from USB stick to your HP Mini and double click. You should then be able to restore the tar file to gain access to your wireless network.